# SOAP and WSDL Webservice in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to create a simple web-service with SOAP and WSDL. I use the built in Soap-server for the handling.
When i try to run the web-service i get this error:

**SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'E:\xampp\htdocs\PHPWebService\blog.wsdl' : Start tag expected, '<' not found**

I have tried putting the Soap-server code in the begin of the code and on the end to see if that resulted in something but it doesn't.

Here is my code:

```
<?php



    class TestClass{
        public function getVar($var){
            return "Value of var = " + $var;
        }
    }

    $oServer = new SoapServer("blog.wsdl");
    $oServer->setClass("TestClass");
    $oServer->handle();

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a RESTful webservice now. So this question doesnt have to be answered no more.
What i did is i used jakesankey's webservice: https://github.com/jakesankey/PHP-RestServer-Class and run this simple code:

I hope anyone find this usefull

```
   <?php
 require_once "RestServer.php";

 class Hello
 {
   public function sayHello($name, $poop)
   {
      // RestServer will encode return objects as JSON
      return array("Response" => "Hello, " . $name . " and dont forget ".$poop);
   }
 }

 $hello = new Hello();
 $rest = new RestServer($hello);
 $rest->handle();

?>
```